# Smudged Corners when using Subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, topology

I'm currently working on a scene, where I'm making some basic models (I have *very* basic modelling skills), and have a mesh made from a cylinder, that after making a few edits to, and applying a bevel + subdivision modifier to, results in this weird geometry:

[image: Smudged corners]

I was able to drastically reduce that, by adding a loop cut, and increasing the subdivision level:

[image]

..but still wondering, what causes that kind of topology? Is it a common issue, that needs to be resolved with loop cuts or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for whoever reads/replies to this

Edit #1

Tried the alternative technique suggested by *moonboots*, which works in keeping the corner sharp with the subdiv modifier, but also results in this weird topology:

[image]
[image]

Edit #2

I must have selected an extra diagonal edge in the previous attempt that created the ngon, but even after select the right edges (I think) I now get the following smoothing:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because of your topology, the *Subdivision Surface* tries to round this corner:

[image]

If you choose this topology instead it will work fine:

[image]

Edit: As I said, you need to avoid ngons on round surfaces because it tends to create artefacts, instead stick to this kind of topology:

[image]

The problem with the topology that you show below is that there are still these 2 faces and the *Subdivision Surface* modifier tends to round the shape, therefore the artefacts:

[image]

See the difference between these two topologies, you need to choose the one on the right, it will be easier to rework and sharpen when you'll give it the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply and demo this to me. I've tried manually subdividing the outer and inner edges of the inset like in your screenshot, and it works!

Though around that corner, there's a bit of a weird bump happening, which I assume is due to the resulting topology (see edit #1 in post). Is there a fix for that too?

Comment: could you please show a picture of the problem or even share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Apologies, was still uploading it, it should now be on the post.

Comment: there's a ngon in your topology, which tends to create artefacts, try to stick to the topology I propose

Comment: I must have selected an extra edge to many, but now reselected and bevelled the correct edges, and now have the original issue (see 'Edit #2'). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps, try not to create ngons because on round surfaces it tends to create artefacts because of the inner triangles that are stretched

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer, on the screenshot you added the notes, that was the previous one with the ngon (at the top), but the version I meant is the one below it).

To make it easier, I've uploaded the Blender file with the model on here: https://pasteall.org/media/7/d/7d43be716e9bb862b92ec57aaadca059.blend

Comment: I've edited again, there's still the same problem as your initial topology, you have this oblique edge that creeates the problem, I'll try to show it more clearly

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, I was trying to wrap my head around what you meant, so the second screenshot with the 2 different topologies helped. The issue though, is that that diagonal one (on the left/bad example) is automatically created when I used the Inset Faces feature, so how would I create the more squared off topology (on the cylinder's curved surface) like your example and Jakemoyo's one?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have said, A good rule of thumb when modeling in subdiv like this is to make sure you have plenty of geo to start with as well. You don't want to be going from a 16 sided cylinder to a 256 sided cylinder in one jump. Try to apply some subdiv modifiers in stages, or at the very least start from a place that is closer to your final result. Big shading distortions and lines on the side of cylinders is a sign that you are asking the subdiv modifier too much.

For example, this cylinder has literally no "special" edge-loops or crazy pro-level geo applied; it's literally just a cylinder with an inset. But since I'm only asking the subdiv modifier to smooth out the final result instead of do half my modeling for me, The result looks a million times better without even trying.

No subdiv Applied:
[image]

With Subdiv Applied:
[image]

Comment: his topology is a bit different as there's a kind of inset for his window but yes I would have avoid this inset

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I've tried your topology (so without the inset face that creates the diagonal edge) and I still get the artefact on the corners from the subdiv modifier.